# Does JRuby implement frozen_string_literal magic comment?

Tags: ruby, jruby, string-interning

The `frozen_string_literal: true` magic comment was [added since Ruby 2.3](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/8976).

However, I cannot find a definitive answer about whether JRuby implements the magic comment.

Or were JRuby already optimized with [string interning](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#intern()) thus rendering the magic comment not necessary?

Comment: According to the docs, JRuby implements Ruby 2.5. If you cannot find an explicit mention that some feature of Ruby 2.5 is not supported, then I would assume that it is implemented. It would be crazy to list every single feature of Ruby 2.5 that is implemented (even the ISO Ruby Spec is already over 300 pages, and that is just a subset of Ruby 1.9, so listing every single feature of Ruby 2.5 would probably be a thousand pages long), therefore only the deviations are listed.